# Cannot display data with React Router and useParams

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router, react-hooks

I am building a React application fetching data from the following API https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/.The components I have are the following:HomePage, UserCard, and DetailPage.
What I want to achieve is: the Homepage component displays a card for each user ( so a list of UserCards components). When clicking on a UserCard I am sent to another page (DetailPage) which renders all the details for that user.
In my HomePage component, I fetch the data with Axios library and then map over the array so to have all the cards displayed with some few details:

```
const Home = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const getUsers = async () => {
    try {
      const users = await axios.get(
        "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"
      );
      setUsers(users.data);

      console.log(users.data);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getUsers();
  }, []);
```

```
  return (
    <div className="style">
      <h1 style={{ textAlign: "center", color: "red", marginBottom: "60px" }}>
        Homepage
      </h1>

      <Grid container spacing={7} justify="center">
        {users.map((user) => (
          <Grid key={user.id} item xs={8} sm={5} md={4}>
            {/*curly braces are used for the prop because it's a dynamic value*/}
            <UserCard
              name={user.name}
              username={"@" + user.username}
              website={user.website}
              id={user.id}
            />
          </Grid>
        ))}
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Until here everything works fine.

My UserCard component has a button that leads to the DetailPage page:

```
<BrowserRouter>
          <div
            className="button-container"
            style={{ width: "100%", display: "flex", justifyContent: "center" }}
          >
            <Button variant="contained" color="primary" disableElevation>
              <Link to={`/ ${props.id}`}>More details</Link>
            </Button>
          </div>
          <Route path="/:id">
            <DetailPage></DetailPage>
          </Route>
        </BrowserRouter>
```

Inside the DetailPage component, I fetch again the data with Axios. Then, I use useParams to get all the URL parameters (in this case, :id)and put them inside an object. Then I want to match the user with the id so to display the correct information. In the console though I get the following error "TypeError: can't access property "name", user is undefined". Is this the correct way to build the application? I am very new to react and I cannot understand what's wrong in my code.

```
function DetailPage() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const getUsers = async () => {
    try {
      const users = await axios.get(
        "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"
      );
      setUsers(users.data);

      console.log(users.data);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getUsers();
  }, []);
  let { id } = useParams();
  console.log(id);
  let user = findUserById(id);
  function findUserById(id) {
    return users.find((o) => o.id === id);
  }

  return (
    <Container>
      <div>
        <h1>{user.name}</h1>
      </div>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are dealing with `asnyc` data fetching, your app needs to handle the period of time while your request are still resloving.

```
let user = findUserById(id);
```

Eventually `user` will resolve to a user object, but its value on the first render will be `undefined` because the `users` array is still empty.

Before accessing any properties on the `user` object, you need to make sure that it actually is an object and not just `undefined`, as accessing properties on `undefined` leads to a fatal error.

You can use the ternary operator or `||` / `&&` statements.

```
return (
    <Container>
    {user ?
      <div>
        <h1>{user.name}</h1>
      </div>
     :
      <div>Loading...<div>
    }
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Or have multiple `return`s:

```
if ( ! user ) {
  return (
    <div>Loading...</div>
  )
}
return (
    <Container>
      <div>
        <h1>{user.name}</h1>
      </div>
    </Container>
  );
```

When dealing with an actual API that has more than one page of data you don't want to have to request all users in order to display one. You would want your `DetailPage` component to request the specific user by their id from a URL like https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/9.